# Can you iterate through and insert values from an array as ids for divs inserted via wrapAll()

Tags: javascript, jquery

This piece of code is part of a script I am working on that dynamically inserts filters and values based on structured HTML content.

The HTML I am dealing with has several H2s that I'd like to wrap in a div with an ID that's equal to the innerHTML of the that H2. In the bigger context, I already have an array of the H2 innerHTML values, but for this example I added a dummy array with the values as a placeholder.

Here is the portion of script that I have that wraps each H2 in a div.

```
var h = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$('h2').each(function () {
    $(this)
        .nextUntil(this.tagName)
        .addBack()
        .wrapAll('<div id="' + h + '" />');
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<h2>a</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>b</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>c</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Expected outcome:

```
<div id="a">
<h2>a</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="b">
<h2>b</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="c">
<h2>c</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just use the `index` passed to the anonymous `each()` function:

```
const h = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

// most jQuery methods have two arguments passed in automatically,
// the first argument is the 'index' of the current node in the
// collection of nodes,
// the second argument is a reference to the current node:
$('h2').each(function(index) {
  $(this)
    .nextUntil(this.tagName)
    .addBack()

    // here we simply supply the index to the Array of h,
    // to have the result concatenated into the string:
    .wrapAll('<div id="' + h[index] + '" />');
});
```

```js
const h = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

$('h2').each(function(index) {
  $(this)
    .nextUntil(this.tagName)
    .addBack()
    .wrapAll('<div id="' + h[index] + '" />');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 0.5em;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

#a {
  border-color: red;
}

#b {
  border-color: lime;
}

#c {
  border-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>a</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>b</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>

<h2>c</h2>
<h3>heading</h3>
<ul>
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/1rhdk4jw/).

Comment: Thank you! And I was so close... Your answer is a huge help.